# Spring Tomcat 404 the origin server did not find a current representation

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am running a Spring app on Tomcat and I continue to get the error mentioned in the post title. I am trying to understand the reason but I cannot figure out. What file should I check that may influence this? Tomcat configurations etc. ?

UPDATE
I noticed that in the project there is an application.xml in meta-inf folder with specified the context-root but this file is not in meta-inf folder inside tomcat webapps deployed

Answer (score 1):

As suspected context root was not defined in Tomcat. This solved the issue.